# Deleting duplicates from a linked list in c?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to just delete duplicates from a linked list so if the list started as [1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5], then the appended list would be [1,2,3,4,5]. Code is below.

```
struct node_h
{
    int data;
    struct node_h* next;
} node;

void remove_h(node* head)
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        if (head->data == head->next->data)
        {
            if (head->next->next == NULL)
            {
                head->next = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                head->next = head->next->next;
            }
        }        
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

The problem is that it segmentation faults. Sometimes.

Comment: Also, you're never `free`ing the node when you remove it from the list (introducing a memory leak).

Comment: You also have a memory leak

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The culprit is `if (head->data == head->next->data)` ... if `head->next` is null, this must segfault.

Check for this condition first, no duplicate is possible, if it is true: Just add `if (head->next == NULL) break;` as a first statement in the while or adapt the while condition.

Answer (score 3):

You're checking to see if `head != NULL` but you don't check to see that `head->next` is non NULL before you access `head->next->data`.